# как обработать ошибку в телеграмм боте?(python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Написал телеграмм бота, код прилагаю.
Когда пишешь ему какую-то лабуду а не город/страну, он выдает ошибку(в консоли а не в боте) и приходится перезагружать бота.

Помогите решить, пожалуйста.

```
import telebot
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('Условный токен', language="ru")
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Условный токен")

from telebot import apihelper


apihelper.proxy = {
    'https': 'socks5h://geek:socks@t.geekclass.ru:7777',  # Замените на данные своего proxy
}

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.get_weather()

    temp = w.get_temperature("celsius")["temp"]


    answer = "В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status() + "\n"
    answer += "Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp) + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer += "Просто дубак, одевайся как танк!"
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Холодно, оденься теплее!"
    else:
        answer += "Тепло, можешь надеть все, что угодно."





    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Используйте try ... except. А если хотите более развёрнутый ответ - приведите полностью текст ошибки.

Comment: 2020-05-05 15:56:56,343 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "NotFoundError occurred, args=('Unable to find the resource',)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 2):

Через условие if (обработает только первую абракадабру, на второй - выдаст ошибку) или while (более эффективно, чем if в данном случае, поскольку должно обрабатывать неверные названия до тех пор, пока не встретит верное) в коде дописать надо. 
То есть:

`while type(<переменная, в которую записывается город>) != str: #AND <здесь условие на наличие введёного города в базе>
print('ERROR')
else:...#и тут код, который будет выполняться, если и город найден в базе, и значение адекватное`

Насколько я понял, данные о температуре бот будет брать с какого-то сайта, если такой город найден не будет, то тоже будет выдавать ошибку. Операнд AND (И) говорит о том, что для успешного выполнения условия должны выполняться оба условия.
Надеюсь, что поможет.